# Extrair formatted_address do JSON de retorno da API do Google Maps

Tags: geolocalização, react-native

Estou utilizando a API do google maps pra fazer o `reverse geocoding` porém não estou conseguindo extrair o `formatted_address`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
      place: 'Localizando endereço...',
      error: null,
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000 },
    );

    axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+ this.state.latitude +','+ this.state.longitude +'&key=AIzaSyDtQ0zsYr1c_V7UmlHFekeFIGM2nDwnDEA')
      .then(results => {
          this.setState({
              place: results[0].formated_address
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            this.setState({ error: error.message })
          });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
        <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.place.toString()}</Text>
        {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Como faço?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Código funcionando (Consegui a resposta no [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46941447/extract-formatted-address-from-json-return-from-google-maps-api/46944166#46944166)):

```
componentWillMount() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => {
    this.setState({
      latitude: position.coords.latitude,
      longitude: position.coords.longitude,
      error: null,
    }, () => this.getGeocode()); // call the api after getCurrentPosition is finished
  },
   (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
   { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000 },
 );

}
getGeocode() {
 axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+ this.state.latitude +','+ this.state.longitude +'&key=__API_KEY__') // be sure your api key is correct and has access to the geocode api
.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
    this.setState({
        place: response.data.results[0].formatted_address // access from response.data.results[0].formatted_address
    })
 }).catch((error) => { // catch is called after then
   this.setState({ error: error.message })
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você está usando o state antes dele atualizar. Tente executar com o willMount assim:

```
componentWillMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });

        axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+ position.coords.longitude +','+ position.coords.latitude +'&key=AIzaSyDtQ0zsYr1c_V7UmlHFekeFIGM2nDwnDEA')
          .then(results => {
              this.setState({
                  place: results[0].formated_address
              })
             .catch((error) => {
                this.setState({ error: error.message })
             });
          });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000 },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Não é, era o formato do retorno que estava errado, tem que ser assim: `response.data.results[0].formatted_address`